# paypal API app error using loginradius

Tags: paypal, loginradius

I have just configured paypal dev for loginRadius and its not working....

The error I get:

> Relying Party Validation error: client_id provided in the request does
>   not match any of the registered clients. Please check the request.

when I go into paypal dev everything looks fine....

have just noted that

REST API CREDENTIALS

Test credentials

Your test credentials are enabled for all features in your app.
Test account - email address has facilitator inserted into it..... is this the issue....

How do i change the email address? I'm not seeing an edit option!